# How to customize run-python function?

Tags: python

I want to use `mac-ports` python instead of default Apple. When I exec `run-python` I get the default python. I could not find any reference under `customize-group`and `customize-variable`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The variable you want is `python-shell-interpreter`.  You can set it with `(setq python-shell-interpreter "/path/to/python")`

Answer (score 2):

Also, if you want to set the Python interpreter on-the-fly, you can do <kbd>C-u</kbd> <kbd>M-x</kbd> <kbd>run-python</kbd>, which will prompt for the interpreter to use:

> `run-python` is an interactive autoloaded compiled Lisp function in
>   `python.el`.
>
> ```
> (run-python &optional CMD DEDICATED SHOW)
> ```
>
> Run an inferior Python process.
>
> Argument `CMD` defaults to `python-shell-calculate-command` return
>   value.  **When called interactively with `prefix-arg`, it allows
>   the user to edit such value** and choose whether the interpreter
>   should be `DEDICATED` for the current buffer.  When numeric prefix
>   arg is other than 0 or 4 do not `SHOW`.
>
> For a given buffer and same values of `DEDICATED`, if a process is
>   already running for it, it will do nothing.  This means that if
>   the current buffer is using a global process, the user is still
>   able to switch it to use a dedicated one.
>
> Runs the hook `inferior-python-mode-hook` after
>   `comint-mode-hook` is run.  (Type <kbd>C-h</kbd> <kbd>m</kbd> in the
>   process buffer for a list of commands.)