# Dedicated Python Shell?

Tags: python, ipython

I just upgraded emacs to 25.3. Before the upgrade when I opened a Python shell, it would ask me whether I wanted a 'dedicated' shell (for the buffer I was in), to which I usually replied 'yes'. Now, I do not have the option. I want a dedicated process (the opposite of [this question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/18137/switch-to-python-shell-without-confirmation)).

I searched the Python options, and didn't see anything that looked promising. Does the 'flying circus' python mode have support for multiple python shells? If not, does anyone know where I can find a version of `python mode` that works with Emacs 25, and has this functionality?

Answer (score 7):

OK, so I figured this out (thanks largely to [this answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/a/14152/13343)). Now, rather than simply typing `C-c C-p`, I use `C-u C-c C-p` to get the options of specifying the Python command I want, and to select a dedicated interpreter.

Because I use dedicated shells so often, I created this fn:

```
(defun my-python-start-or-switch-repl (&optional msg)
  "Start and/or switch to the REPL."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (python-shell-get-process)
      (python-shell-switch-to-shell)
    (progn
      (run-python (python-shell-calculate-command) t t)
      (python-shell-switch-to-shell)
      )
    )
  )
```

And mapped it to `C-c !` with:

```
(add-hook 'python-mode-hook
          (lambda () (define-key python-mode-map (kbd "C-c !") 'my-python-start-or-switch-repl))
          )
```

Now `C-c !` either opens the shell for the current buffer, or opens a *new dedicated* python shell.