# Dedicated python shells that runs the code

Tags: shell, ipython

This [answer](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/36520/dedicated-python-shell) how to map `C-c !` to create a new python shell for the current buffer.

The main code is this:

```
(defun my-python-start-or-switch-repl (&optional msg)
  "Start and/or switch to the REPL."
  (interactive "p")
  (if (python-shell-get-process)
      (python-shell-switch-to-shell)
    (progn
      (run-python (python-shell-calculate-command) t t)
      (python-shell-switch-to-shell)
      )
    )
  )
```

As it can be seen, it uses `run-python`, so it only opens a shell that has the name of the buffer it was opened it from, e.g., if the program is `foo.py`, then the shell has the name: `*Python[foo.py]*`, but it doesn't run `foo.py`. Is there a way to have dedicated shells that by default run the program from which they being generated?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to do what you need modifying your function like this:

```
defun my-python-start-or-switch-repl (&optional msg)
"Start and/or switch to the REPL."
(interactive "p")
(if (python-shell-get-process)
    (progn
      (python-shell-send-buffer)
      (python-shell-switch-to-shell)
      )
  (progn
    (run-python (python-shell-calculate-command) t t)
    (other-window 1)
    (python-shell-send-buffer)
    (python-shell-switch-to-shell)
    )
  )
)
```

The main change is the call to `python-shell-send-buffer` that sends the entire current buffer to the running Python process.